# Prototype equivalent for jQuery closest function

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Is there any equivalent in Prototype for the jQuery closest function?

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the [`up`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/methods/up) method. It is not quite equivalent, since `closest` also considers the current element. So you would need to first test your selected element to see if it matches your criteria, if it does not, use the `up`-method:

```
jQuery:
return $('#id').closest('li');

Prototype:
var element = $('id')
return element.match('li') ? element : element.up('li');
}
```

Comparison:

**.closest()**

- Begins with the current element
- Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
- Returns a jQuery object that contains zero or one element

**.up()**

- Begins with the parent element
- Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
- Returns an extended Element object, or undefined if it doesn't match

You can easily extend Prototype to include this method for all elements like so:

```
// Adds a closest-method (equivalent to the jQuery method) to all 
// extended Prototype DOM elements
Element.addMethods({
   closest: function closest (element, cssRule) {
      var $element = $(element);
      // Return if we don't find an element to work with.
      if(!$element) {
         return;
      }
      return $element.match(cssRule) ? $element : $element.up(cssRule);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.next('.className')`  or `.next('divId')`

There is also `.previous()`, `.down()` and `.up()`, depending on where you're looking.